# React: select event in div with multiple span elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a React component with parsed text:

The html structure is like:

```
<div>
    <span>It's a </span>
    <span className="highlight-text">cat</span>
</div>
```

How I can have a event listener which enable I pass all selected text within this div? For example, if I select "a ca", the event listener can get e.target.value = "a ca".

It is possible the highlight part will be repeating within the full text, for example:

```
<div>
    <span>It's a slim cat, not a fat </span>
    <span className="highlight-text">cat</span>
</div>
```

In this case, the selection listener will get 2nd part string, start position of whole text.

[image: a]

Answer (score 0):

This is the first thing that comes to mind.

```
// Example impl
<Component text="This is a cat" highlight="is a" />

// Component render
render() {
    const {
        text,
        highlight,
    } = this.props;
    // Returns the start index for your high light string
    // in our example 'is a' starts at index 5
    const startHighlightTextIdx = text.search(highlight);

    // Create a substring for the first part of the string
    // ie: 'This is '
    const startText = text.substring(0, startHighlightTextIdx);

    // Create a substring for the last part of the string
    // For this substr we want to start where our startHighlightTextIdx starts 
    // and we want to add the length of the highlighted string
    // in order to ignore the highlighted string
    // ie: start at index 5 + 4 (highlight text length) so substr(9) to end
    const endText = text.substring(
        startHighlightTextIdx + highlight.length,
    );
    <div>
        <span>{startText}</span>
        <span className="highlight-text">{highlight}</span>
        <span>{endText}</span>
    </div>
}

v2:
// This might be a cleaner solution
// explode by the hightlight string and grab index 0 and last
// this outputs ["This ", " cat"]
const textParts = text.split(highlight);
const startText = textParts[0];
const endText = textParts[1];
```

Comment: How if there's duplicates of highlight text part? how to get the start position of selected text?

Comment: The first impl would ignore additional strings, are you trying to do something like a full text search engine? So for example: `This is a string with letters` let's say you want the `i` you want all `i's` to be highlighted?

Comment: Yeal, I tried this, but when the text has repeated highlight parts, I don't know how I can get start position of the highlight in whole text within div. Do you have any suggestions? thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

I got one answer myself, in order to get the selected text, I can just use window.getSelection().

But not sure if there's a risk

Comment: this solution also can not get start position of highlight if there're duplicated hightlights in text